# Why do websites try to hide their front-end technoloies?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-deployment

Recently I started learning web development. I tried to read the HTML and CSS  codes of some famous websites in my web browser. But I observed that they intentionally mess everything such as changing the real names of the bootstrap classes, while looking at the design architecture and page layout anyone could guess what kinds of technologies are used.
What would be the possible reasons?
I think it's not about security because any average programmer can still know everything about their front-end technologies if he puts some efforts.

Comment: Recent [hot network question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211189/is-open-sourcing-the-code-of-a-webapp-not-recommended) on this subject

Comment: "*I observed that they intentionally mess everything such as changing the real names of the bootstrap classes*" are you sure that's made specifically to *hide* stuff or is it just a byproduct of minification which is done to reduce the size of the code?

Comment: am pretty sure that what youi see is the result of minifacation and not anyone trying to hide code https://www.toptal.com/javascript/optimize-js-and-css-with-gulp

Comment: Since you mentioned bootstrap classes, you should not include ALL bootstrap into your project, but use their SASS/SCSS to include ONLY the classes you need, while doing that, its usualy nice to have custom class names.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple reasons.

Some companies, indeed, try to obfuscate some of all of the code to hinder some of the attacks. That is not 100% proof, of course, because a sophisticated actor can still reverse engineer almost any code that's out in the open.

However, most of the times it's simply how modern frontend development is done nowadays. The trend has been moving more and more towards using various build, bundle, code-minification and packaging tools. Like Webpack, for example.

What you see simply is a result of source code being processed packaged for optimal delivery and running in the browser.

The days when we could view web-page source and inspect pure HTML/JS/CSS, as it was written by the original developer, are long gone.